# App doesn't response after got content of URL

Tags: c#, macos, swift

I a absolute new beginner with Swift. So i wanted to get a string from URL (in C#:

```
wc = System.Net.WebClient();
string response = wcDownloadString("url");
```

)

In Swift i tried that:

```
func StrToUrl(newURL: String) -> NSURL
{
    return NSURL(string: newURL)!;
}

func DataToStr(getData: NSData) -> String
{
    var datastring = NSString(data: getData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String;
    return datastring;
}
func getStringFromURL(url: String) -> String
{
    return DataToStr(NSData(contentsOfURL: StrToUrl(url))!);
}

func action()
{
    let tmpNewsCount = getStringFromURL("http://example.com");  // STUCK HERE
    L_lastSeen.setValue("Got String: " + tmpNewsCount);
}
```

But after i started the function action(), my app doesn't response.

Seems like Mac App functions are running asynchron. So i can start other functions in my App, too!?

*Thank You!*

Comment: Stuck or you get an exception?

Comment: I doesn't get any messages from Xcode and the app is still running, but at this point, the function do stuck.

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint at that line, and then when the debugger stops, press "step into" to see precisely at what point inside the function it stucks.

Comment: Ok, i found the problem: 'RF_1.setValue(25);'. I have excluded this and i have got the String "7" (Thats right). **Thank you very much!**